# how can i send and get messages from database using AJAX JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a website using PHP and AJAX JQUERY. And inside this website, there is texting system, like whatsapp, telegram ...etc.

and I'm wanna get all the messages from the database after the user send a message, using jQuery AJAX. so far I have been able to send the text to the database successfully but I fail when I try to get the messages.

I Have this following code when first the page is loaded:

```
<div class="messaging-frame">
    <div class="Title-in-message">
        <h4 class="title-message"><?php echo $index['Title'] ?></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="messaging-box" id="messages">
        <?php
        // THE MESSAGE FROM MESSAGE TABLE
        foreach ($messages as $key => $value) {

            if ($_SESSION['EmployeeNum'] === $value['Sender']) { ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col" style="margin-bottom:15px">
                        <div class='sent'>
                            <p id='send-bubble'> <?php
                                                    echo $value['Message'] ?> </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
            } else { ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col" style="margin-bottom:15px">
                        <div class='recived' id="recieved-bubble">
                            <p id='recived-bubble'><?php echo $value['Message'] ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><?php
                    }
                }
                        ?>
    </div>\
```

Than this code in AJAX jQuery get executed when ever the user send a new message in messaging box:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sending_text').click(function() {
        var report = $('#report_num').val()
        var reportInt = parseInt(report);
        var text = $('#text_sent').val();
        var encodeText = encodeURIComponent(text);

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'DisplayTicket/sendNewText' ?> ",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                text: text,
                reportNum: reportInt
            },
            success: function() {
                
                $('#messages').load("<?php echo base_url() . 'DisplayTicket/getNewMessages' ?>", {reportNum: reportInt}, function() {
                    var texts = " <?php foreach ($messages as $k => $val) { if ($_SESSION['EmployeeNum'] === $value['Sender']) { ?>";

                    texts += " <div class='row'> <div class='col' style='margin-bottom:15px'> <div class='sent'>";
                    texts += "<?php echo $val['Message'] ?>";
                    texts += "</div> </div> </div>";
                    texts += "<?php } else {  ?>";
                    texts += " <div class='row'> <div class='col' style='margin-bottom:15px'> <div class='recived' id='recieved-bubble'>"
                    texts += "<?php echo $val['Message'] ?>";
                    texts += "</div> </div> </div>"
                    texts += "<?php }
                                    } ?>";
                    texts += "</div>";
                    $('#messages').html(texts);

                })
            },
        });
            
    });
})
```

Keep in mind that the `$('#messages').html(texts);`
is actually get executed but the newest messages in not added

Comment: If you want to use AJAX then you'll need to implement a polling pattern whereby you make a request to the server at intervals to check if there's new messages and display them. Research [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) and [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout). ***However*** it should be noted that AJAX polling is not a good solution for production environments. For chat systems you should look to use something like Websockets to reduce server load and decrease delays between messages being sent/received

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `.load()` method to fill the `#messages` .
Normally the first argument to this method is the response you wanna insert,and the this is just a callback after success, and you are using a php variable $messages  instead of using the response from the request.

I see already 2 ways of doing this:
1 - remove the callback from `load()`  and make sure the response is well written in html as youy want

2 - get rid of `load()` function, and call another ajax inside success of the first ajax to accomplish so.

The second method is just to make you understand what is wrong. So the best way to do it is to fix `load()` method accordingly